# Trying to load janusgraph with local backend cassandra and elastic search

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, cassandra, janusgraph

I am using Spark to load JanusGraph with Cassandra backend and Elasticsearch, both running locally.

```js
     val conf = new BaseConfiguration()


     conf.setProperty("storage.backend", "cassandrathrift")
     conf.setProperty("storage.hostname", "127.0.0.1")
     conf.setProperty("index.search.backend","elasticsearch")
     conf.setProperty("index.search.hostname", "127.0.0.1")
    
     val gr = JanusGraphFactory.open(conf)
```

I am however, getting this error,

```bash
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find implementation class: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager
        at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:61)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:477)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:409)
        at org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1376)
        at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:164)
        at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:133)
        at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:113)
        at Test2$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcVI$sp(make_graph3.scala:177)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
        at Test2$.main(make_graph3.scala:162)
        at Test2.main(make_graph3.scala)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:56)
        ... 10 more
```

I tried running JPS on terminal, and this is the output:

```bash
>32689 NailgunRunner
>
>44609 GremlinServer
>
>32162 
>
>44917 Jps
>
>44326 CassandraDaemon
>
>44744 Launcher
>
>44509 Elasticsearch
```

So, Cassandra and ES both are running. What could be the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As with almost all ClassNotFoundException, doesn't matter if external services are running. Your code is missing a JAR on the classpath to communicate with them

Comment: I have added it to my IntelliJ project. Is there some specific way to do this?

Comment: Added what? Are you using sbt? Can you show your dependencies?

Comment: For example, you need this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.janusgraph/janusgraph-cassandra